# Ruby on Rails asset recompiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

With ruby on rails application, does assets needs to be totally recompiled? or is RoR smart enough to pick out the assets that did not change?

ie) If I changed 1 js file out of 100 js files, is there a way to recompile the 1 js file? OR do I have to wait for 100 js files to be compressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails doesn't differentiate between modified and unmodified assets as of yet.  However, you can install [turbo-sprockets-rails3](https://github.com/ndbroadbent/turbo-sprockets-rails3) gem for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into this gem! I have been experimenting in submodules for this problem.